# Проблема с capitalize(). Python

Tags: python, строки

Возникла проблема с функцией capitalize(). Программа получает на вход строку, которая состоит из символов в разных регистрах. На выходе я должен получить ту же самую строку, если 1 - ый символ этой строки находится в верхнем регистре и строку с первым символом в верхнем регистре, если до этого он был в нижнем.

Код:

```
string = str(input())
print(string if string[0].isupper() else string.capitalize())
```

Пример работы:

```
konjac
Konjac

ApPLe
ApPLe
```

Проблема возникает, если во входных данных находится такая строка:

```
xYaPxPxHxGePfGtQySlNrLxSjDtNnTaRaEpAhPaQpWnDzMqGgRgEwJxGiBdZnMtHxFbObCaGiCeZkUqIgBhHtNvAqAlHp
Xyapxpxhxgepfgtqyslnrlxsjdtnntaraepahpaqpwndzmqggrgewjxgibdznmthxfbobcagicezkuqigbhhtnvaqalhp
```

На выходе я должен был получить ту же самую строку, где только первый символ (x) будет в верхнем регистре, но все последующие символы по какой - то причине конвертируются в нижний, хотя этого быть не должно.

UPD: Проблема решена. Функция capitalize() возвращает строку с 0 -ым символом в верхнем регистре, но при этом конвертирует все остальные символы в нижний регистр. Чтобы изменить только 0 - ый символ в строке - используем ф-ию upper() для 0 - го символа и присоединяем остальную часть строки.

Рабочий код:

```
string = str(input())
print(string if string[0].isupper() else string[0].upper() + string[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourstring = yourstring[0].upper() + yourstring[1:]
```

Comment: @Chloe Потому что именно так работает capitalize - делает большую первую букву и маленькие остальные

Comment: Довольно странно, т.к в определении этой функции не указано, что она все последующие символы конвертирует в нижний регистр. Спасибо!

Comment: @CrazyElf Еще вопрос: "Если capitalize() работает именно так, то почему в том же слове "ApPLe" я получаю ту же строку, а не измененную на другую с символами в нижнем регистре?

Comment: @Chloe Неправда, получаешь именно "Apple"...

Comment: @Chloe указано: Return a copy of the string with its first character capitalized **and the rest lowercased**. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize